# MQTT Server Failure Cycle for the Server's Client(on Same App)

Tags: delphi, wireshark, mqtt

I'm working on an MQTT Server Application in Pascal with Delphy XE2 for connection with other application which contain MQTT Client and an Android'App which can receive information and send recept Ack. For a good using , i need a good retention for that.

On the Server application, I have make a MQTT Client for follow the activity of my system and check the good trafic of message.

This application is good, no memory leak(verify with FastMM) and all the functionnality is ok (I have check everything...). But i don't understand, all work good during few day, and in a moment, my server stop to listen the Client.

I can destroy client & server's Object, re-make and re-connect, nothing can repair the application , i must close and open new processus of my Server.

After seek on Internet, i have no found any information about a failure cycle like that.

Exactly, it's always the same following of behavior :

1. All is Ok.
2. My Client try to send a message but fail.It try 8 time (MaxRetry).
3. It's disconnected him-self.After that, it reconnect all the time, because he is on the same computer, but he fail all the message launch.
4. It disconnection-reconnection repeat and finish by leads the disconnection of the other clients because of it's the main pillar of the transmission.
   //Return to usually

Configuration Client :

```
TTClientComp.AutoSubscribe := false;
TTClientComp.Broker := false;
TTClientComp.Clean := TRUE;
TTClientComp.Host := 'localhost';
TTClientComp.KeepAlive := 10;
TTClientComp.LocalBounce := false;
TTClientComp.MaxRetries := 8;
TTClientComp.Port := 1883;
TTClientComp.RetryTime := 60;
TTClientComp.Tag := 0;
TTClientComp.ClientID:='ClServ';
```

Configuration Server

```
TTServeurComp.Port := 1883;
TTServeurComp.RetryTime := 60;
TTServeurComp.MaxRetries := 4;
TTServeurComp.Tag := 0;
TTServeurComp.LocalBounce := false;
```

If someone can help me , you're welcome.

Sorry for my English, i'm trainning me to be better ;)

Thank's for reading and for time.

/////////////////////////

Edit for com :: 
(See on WireShark)   (37.124, 139.1 , 37.248 is Client, 175 is Server)

This follow of message appears cyclicaly for 3min and 7 sec and is at the same moment of my error. It's not usually for me to use that logiciel , if some one can explain me fastly , he will be cool because I don't know wath is , for exemple ,"tapeware" ;)

Discussion normal //

> 37.175 > 37.248   Ack         ibm-mqisdp > 57080
>
> 139.1  > 37.175   Psh,Ack     50562 > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 139.1    Psh,Ack     ibm-mqisdp > 50562
>
> 137.1  > 37.175   Ack         50562 > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Psh,Ack     tapeware > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Ack         ibm-mqisdp > tapeware

Bug //

> 37.248 > 37.175   Fin,Ack    **57080** > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.248   Ack        ibm-mqisdp > 57080
>
> 37.175 > 37.248   Fin,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > 57080
>
> 37.248 > 37.175   Ack        57080 > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.248 > 37.175   Syn        **59022** > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.248   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > 59022

/!\ The  first Client is disconnected now by the Server Application (it'is an Android phone or tablet tactil)

> 37.175 > 37.124   Fin,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > **tapeware**
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Ack        tapeware > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Fin,Ack    tapeware > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Ack        ibm-mqisdp > tapeware
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Fin,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > **crinis-hb**
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Ack        crinis-hb > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Fin,Ack    crinis-hb > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Ack        ibm-mqisdp > crinis-hb
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Fin,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > **epl-slp**
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Ack        epl-slp > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Fin,Ack    epl-slp > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Ack        ibm-mqisdp > epl-slp
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        **rnm** > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > rnm

/!\ Here , I think the others client begin to be disconnected , but I have clean a little for have only one client.

> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        rnm > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > rnm
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        rnm > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > rnm
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        **v-one-spp** > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp >  v-one-spp
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        v-one-spp > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp >  v-one-spp
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        **an-pcp** > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp >  an-pcp
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        **v-one-spp** > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp >  v-one-spp
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        **an-pcp** > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp >  an-pcp
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        an-pcp > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp >  an-pcp
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        **item** > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > item
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        item > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > item
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        item > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > item
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        **spw_dnspreload** > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > spw_dnspreload
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        spw_dnspreload > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > spw_dnspreload
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        **qtms-bootstrap** > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp >  qtms-bootstrap
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        **spw_dnspreload** > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > spw_dnspreload
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        **qtms-bootstrap** > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp >  qtms-bootstrap
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        qtms-bootstrap > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp >  qtms-bootstrap
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        **spectraport** > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp >  spectraport
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        spectraport > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp >  spectraport
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        spectraport > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp >  spectraport
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        **sse-app-config**> ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > sse-app-config
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        sse-app-config> ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > sse-app-config
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        **sscan** > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > sscan
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        **sse-app-config**> ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > sse-app-config
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        **sscan** > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > sscan
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        sscan > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > sscan
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Psh,Ack    **dvapps** > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Ack        ibm>-mqisdp > dvapps
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        **opentrac** > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > opentrac
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        opentrac > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > opentrac
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        opentrac > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > opentrac
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        **informer** > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > informer
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        informer > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > informer
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        **trap-port** > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > trap-port
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        **informer** > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > informer
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        **trap-port** > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > trap-port
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        trap-port > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > trap-port
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        **trap-port-mom** > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > trap-port-mom
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        trap-port-mom > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > trap-port-mom
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        trap-port-mom > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > trap-port-mom
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        trap-port-mom > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > trap-port-mom
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        **nav-port** > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > nav-port
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        nav-port > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > nav-port
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        **sasp** > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > sasp
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        **nav-port** > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > nav-port
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        **sasp** > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > sasp
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Syn        sasp > ibm-mqisdp
>
> 37.175 > 37.124   Rst,Ack    ibm-mqisdp > sasp
>
> 37.124 > 37.175   Fin, Ack   ibm-mqisdp > **xxnetserver**

/!\ And now , the client begin to be reconnected 
. But they can't communicate, the Server just let them connect & substract

It isn't the same message all the time, but usually very similar

I'm going to seek ^^

Thank a lot =)

Comment: 'My Client try to send a message but fail' - how does it fail exactly? Is there an error message, an exception?

Comment: No Exception.
Just proceed in the TimerProc of MQTT , the message retry to be publish but not be receive. so the client is disconnected by the server. But the client is on the same app so i don't understand why the connection is not steady...

Comment: Did you try to analyze network traffic (using Wireshark)?

Comment: up =) 
Sorry i haven't find other way for this issue without the deleting of the serveur ... Someone can help ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to take a deep look into your MQTT broker code and logs.
Look at the broker implementation of the MQTT Clean Session flag, that can cause some blocks when trying to reconnect with same client id and clean session:

`clean_session`
If False, the client is a durable client and subscription information and queued messages will be retained when the client disconnects.

`clean_session`
If True, the broker will remove all information about this client when it disconnects.

Comment: @Guillaume I know this is an old question, but I am curious to find out if this worked for you? Thanks.